# KendoUI grid validation IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui

I have an issue with **KendoUI** grid validation and IE8. I have some fields not required and that works correctly in IE9/10 and Chrome and Firefox.

However in IE8 all fields fail validation unless they have a value - i.e., validation: `{required: false}` has no effect.

Comment: disabled validation for now just for IE8 until i can come up with a better solution

Comment: It turns out that this is only an issue for IE8 when you are emulating with IE developer tools. See [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/non-mandatory-fields-in-ie8-becomes-mandatory-(ie9-chrome-it-works-fine).aspx)

Comment: I am running IE8 on Win7 using Virtual Box. I have two inputs that have `required="false"` for both of them. I am getting the same issue in that they are saying "these fields are required" when they are not, but I am not using IE developer tools to simulate IE8.